# SpreadsheetLight. Search and Replace

Tags: c#, spreadsheetlight

I have "source.xlsx" and "destination.xlsx".
Source.xlsx has a list of serialNumbers, one per row (in column "SerialN").

Destination.xlsx has the same serialNumbers, one per row (in column "SerialN").

I wish to go trough each of the serialNumber in "source.xml and find the equivalent in "destination.xlsx"
(in column "SerialN").

If number is a match then, in "destination.xlsx" column labelled "Pass?" enter "passed".

I am new to Spreadsheet Light, and classify myself ha a beginner in C#.
I have seen many examples, on the developer site and this site, but got confused about it.

Can you please help?

Regards
Francesco C

NOTE: I have changed xls to xlsx. made an error.

Comment: Spreadsheet Light doesn't seem to support xls format. If Excel is installed on the machine where the program will run, you can look into Excel Interop, or VBA macro

Comment: So I could convert to xlxs easly. Then what?